# Web page does not run shell script

Tags: php, html, linux, apache2, nvidia-jetson-nano

I've made a simple webpage that has to run some simple bash scripts. I run apache2 on Jetson Nano and I have three files in `/var/www/html` folder:

- index.html
- testexec.php
- test.sh

First one looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>TEST</title>
     </head>
  <body>
    <form action="testexec.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Create file">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

the php file:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("test.sh");
header('Location: http://192.168.25.16/index.html?success=true');
?>
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash


touch file.txt
```

My problem is that everything looks good, but the scrit doesn't run. In future it will be used to run program written in python, but for now I can't run even that simple one. Is the problem with location of files or with something else?

I've already tried to change php file

```
$output = shell_exec("test.sh");
```

with

```
$output = exec("test.sh");
```

with or without `$output`

My browser (firefox) returns no errors in console.

Script works fine when I run it from shell. It is executable.

I've already tried to look for similar problems, but there were no solutions.

Comment: `shell_exec("./test.sh");`

Comment: Same situation, doesn't work.

Comment: Try echoing `$output` to see. Also add `2>&1` to the end of the command so you get error messages.

Comment: echoing `$output` doesn't print anything. In the end of which command should I put `2>&1`?

Comment: Then it should be working. What happens if the shell script prints something, do you see that in the `echo $output;`?

Comment: When script echos something I can see it but i had to comment line `header('Location: http://192.168.25.16/index.html?success=true');`

Comment: Of course, if you redirect you don't see the output. But that means the script is running. Try using the absolute path to the file you want to touch, it's probably doing it in an unexpected directory.

Comment: absolute paths also give no result

Comment: So the script is running, it's just that the `touch` command doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think so, script works straight from shell, with other scripts, which are supposed to run simple python programs, I have same problems

Comment: I'm just trying to understand exactly what's going wrong when you run this script from PHP. If you put echo commands in the script, you see the output. But if you put a `touch` command in the script, it doesn't work, and doesn't print an error message, either.

Comment: If you put echo commands before and after the touch command, you see both of them?

Comment: Can you write the full command that I should check?

Comment: Put this in the shell script: `echo before touch; touch file.txt; echo after touch`

Comment: Put `$output = shell_exec("./test.sh 2>&1"); echo $output;` in the PHP script, and remove the redirect.

Comment: it prints only before and after touch. Only what's on shell script, any output from php. Also file wasn't created

Comment: Add `pwd` to the shell script, so you're sure that it's creating the file in the directory you expect.

Comment: you mean `echo pwd`?

Comment: No, just `pwd`. It prints the current working directory.

Comment: `pwd; touch file.txt`

Comment: Oh, I've made some changes and now output is like: before touch: cannot touch 'file.txt': Permission denied after

Comment: That means the web userid doesn't have write permission to the directory where you're trying to create the file.

Comment: But file has 777 previlliges

Comment: how can I fix IT?

Comment: The file already exists? I thought you were tryiing to create the file.

Comment: i mean the shell script file

Comment: The permission problem is with the directory where you're trying to create the file, not the script.

Comment: Directory write permission controls who can create/delete/rename files in the directory.

Comment: so should I change tej ownership od whole folders on Path `/var/www/html/`? because html is owned by my user on Jetson

Comment: Or maybe it's about something else

Answer (score 0):

Very often the problem is with user rights, first try installing `chmod 777 test.sh` to just check if this is the problem.
In addition, you should go back to the exec documentation

```
exec(string $command, array &$output = null, int &$result_code = null): string|false
```

and check what `$result_code` is equal to.

If we get echo result!:

```php
$output=null;
$retval=null;
exec('echo $(pwd);', $output, $retval);
echo "${retval} with value:\n";
print_r($output);
```

Comment: He says in a comment he's getting output from the script if he adds an echo, so it's not a permission problem.

Comment: if we get a response from echo then it is worth checking echo $(pwd).

Comment: *0 with value: Array ( [0] => /var/www/html ) *    <-- this is response to your script

Comment: but `exec('touch file.txt', $output, $retval);` the file is not created?

Comment: it didn't create file

Comment: Please show output `stat /var/www/html` and `systemctl | grep php` and `systemctl status phpX.X-fpm.service`. I have replicated your code on my local server. My file is being created. I am sure that the reason is precisely the lack of rights for the user to create files. You need to check the php-fpm user.